# Tomcat: Java Static Variable Scope, Application or session wide?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, web-applications, scope

Are java static variables shared across all sessions using the same webapp or does each session gets its own version of the static variables?

To put it another way, do Tomcat created a new set of classes for each session or just one set for the whole web app?

Comment: static are class-level, they will be created only when the class holder is loaded.. they don't belong to objects

Comment: What do you mean by session? An HTTP session? That's just an object, has nothing to do with static variables/class loading.

Comment: I think they meant request rather than session

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tomcat creates one `ClassLoader` for each web application, i.e. war-File or context. So every `Class` is loaded once for the web application. Therefore static variables are shared across multiple sessions and requests.

**References:**

- [Apache Tomcat 7 Classloader Howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

Answer (score 3):

Static variables are shared across the sessions.
Be careful of using static variables.