# How to not keep Static variable across multiple request with Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

According to this post [Tomcat: Java Static Variable Scope, Application or session wide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554464/tomcat-java-static-variable-scope-application-or-session-wide) Tomcat retains static variable across request, how can it be configured to not keep static variable per request?

Comment: You "configure" it to not keep static variables by not using static variables in *your* code.

Answer (score 2):

No it can't.  It is not practical.

The Java Language Specification (JLS) *mandates* that there is one and only instance of a classes static variables in the entire execution context (i.e. the JVM).

The only *possible* "get out" is that it is technically possible to have multiple copies of the same class, each in different classloaders.  However, creating a new classloader and loading a new copy of a class for each request would be horribly inefficient, and totally impractical.

The solution is simple:

> Don't use statics in your request processing classes.

Comment: I have my own classloaders that load jars on the fly maybe this is the reason

Comment: Well ... yea ... if you are doing stuff like that (in Tomcat server, or anything), then using statics in your dynamically loaded classes is a bad idea.